# Tesseract, como integrá-lo?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

Como integrar o Tesseract à minha aplicação no Eclipse? Preciso fazer reconhecimento de imagem.

Comment: Vieira, chegou a olhar o `Tess4j`? É um Wrapper para Java, que serve para Android. Dê uma olhada em: http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Você chegou a pesquisar no Google? O que você descobriu?

Comment: Aqui existe um tutorial de como fazer isso e um código-fonte de exemplo.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19533854/1565769